# Accessing a pandas.DataFrame column name with a '.' in it

Tags: pandas, select, indexing, dataframe, period

I have a pandas dataframe `df`.  One of the columns is `Project.Fwd_Primer`.

I would like to access that  column, however when I use
`df.Project.Fwd_Primer` I get:

> AttributeError.

Is there another way I can access this column, or do I need to get rid of the period in it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `[]`:

```
df['Project.Fwd_Primer']
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Project.Fwd_Primer': {0: '1', 1: '2'}})

print (df)
    Project.Fwd_Primer
0                  1
1                  2
  
print (df['Project.Fwd_Primer'])
0    1
1    2
Name: Project.Fwd_Primer, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

You can also check [attribute access in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access):

**Warning**

> You can use this access only if the **index** element is a valid python identifier, e.g. **s.1** is not allowed. See here for an explanation of valid identifiers.
>
> The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. **s.min** is not allowed.
>
> Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: **index**, **major_axis**, **minor_axis**, **items**, **labels**.
>
> In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. **s['1']**, **s['min']**, and **s['index']** will access the corresponding element or column.
>
> The Series/Panel accesses are available starting in 0.13.0.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
df['Project.Fwd_Primer']
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there were so many ways to access it