# Changing a Data Frame over a string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change Categorical Data from my data frame using the code

```
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sex','n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class',
               'embark_town', 'alone']
for i in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  dfTrain[i] = pd.factorize(dfTrain.i)[0]
dfTrain.head()
```

But I get the error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Use `dfTrain[i]` instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Pandas column using squared brackets vs using a dot (like an attribute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130255/accessing-pandas-column-using-squared-brackets-vs-using-a-dot-like-an-attribute)

Comment: And similar duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343451/for-i-in-list-accessing-and-using-i-to-index-into-a-pandas-dataframe) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883798/accessing-a-pandas-dataframe-column-name-with-a-in-it). The former being exactly your question.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not an attribute, you can't use dot notation:

```
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sex','n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class',
                       'embark_town', 'alone']

for i in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    dfTrain[i] = pd.factorize(dfTrain[i])[0]  # .i -> [i]
```

**Update**

If you use `sklearn`, you can use [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

oe = OrdinalEncoder()
dfTrain[CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS] = oe.fit_transform(dfTrain[CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS])
```

and use `transform_inverse` to decode numeric values.